# Angularjs - Ng-Tble - Not Defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm having issues creating an ngTable. I can get arrays that create manually to render fine, but when I hook this up to my api, it fails. With no error of course, so I'm really confused why. I get a $scope.data array does get filled like expected, but the new tableParams always ends up undefined.

Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="demoController as demo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="page-header">Pharmacy Rebate Portal</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Default configuration</h3>
            <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
                <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
                    <td data-title="'Manufacturer'">{{row.manufacturer | uppercase }} </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using this version of ngTable. Along with 1.6.3 Angular. Any ideas?

https://unpkg.com/ng-table/bundles/ng-table.min.js

```
$http.get('/api/rebates').
            then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
                $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10,          // count per page
                    sorting: {
                        foo: 'asc'     // initial sorting
                    }
                }, {
                        total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
                        getData: function ($defer, params) {
                            // use build-in angular filter
                            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                                $scope.data;

                            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        }
                    });
            });`
```

Comment: You need to use callback function to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is always synchronous. So what is happening here, `$scope.data=response;` is executing before `$http.get('/api/rebates')...` completed. It means, `$scope.data` undefined. To Solve this problem, I recommend to use Service.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
  myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, dataService){

  dataService.dataLists(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.data=response.data;
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10,          // count per page
                    sorting: {
                        foo: 'asc'     // initial sorting
                    }
                }, {
                        total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
                        getData: function ($defer, params) {
                            // use build-in angular filter
                            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                                $scope.data;

                            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        }
                    });
  });

});
}])

myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
    this.dataLists = function(callback){
   $http.get('/api/rebates').then(callback)
  }
});
```

Comment: This may be more elegant, but my $scope.data is defined okay. The $scope.tableParams isn't defined.

Comment: @AlexPeasley, if you follow my solution it should solve that problem as well. Let me know if does not

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I get this currently. TypeError: dataService.dataLists is not a function

Comment: @AlexPeasley, I would like to see your code. Better if you add your complete code on jsfiddle so that I can inspect.

Comment: Service should be after controller not before. Like: https://jsfiddle.net/rsLrdj57/5/

Comment: I filipped it and added angular/ng-table. Still having core issues. https://jsfiddle.net/alexpeasley/rsLrdj57/6/  I'm new to fiddle.....

Answer (score 0):

The `$` sign seems to be the mistake. Have you tried:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in demo.data">
```

**Edit:**

Haven't tested it, but I think this is the way to go:

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
  page: 1,
  count: 10,         
  sorting: {
    foo: 'asc'
  }
}, 
{
  getData: function(params) {
    return $http.get('/api/rebates')
      .then(function(response) {
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                          $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :        
                          $scope.data;

        return orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(),  
                                 params.page() * params.count());
      });
});
```

Comment: This just displays the data in my array, it doesn't actually used the ng-table implementation

Comment: Sorry, I focused on the wrong thing. I would try moving the `$http.get` into the `getData` function. Maybe this example helps: http://ng-table.com/#/loading/overview

Comment: I've looked at that and this link. http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-external-array. The issue I was having there is that http/resource query's were not resolving before I ran the ngtable call, so there wasn't any data to use. That's why I embedded it underneath the http call.